# ActionBar default color

Tags: android, colors

I'm using the Action Bar for the top of my screen and have buttons there. i'd like an additional sequence of butons at the bottom, but there's too many controls for it to fit in the Action Bar, so I'm creating a Custom View and layout. I'm trying to match the color scheme of hte Action Bar, but I can't figure out what the default Android.R.Color is for the Action Bar.

I've set the custom view's layout as shown. There doesn't seem to be a built in color for light_gray, or anything indicating a menu or action bar default color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333"/>
</shape>
```

[image: Screenshot of difference between top and bottom]

Comment: @Stealth were you able to scale main actionBar icon to rectangular shape? If yes,then how did you do that.plz reply,need it badly

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu I really don't know what you're talking about. The actoin bar is rectangular, yes. I didn't do anything special to scale/reshape it. it's a rectangle.

Comment: read again,I have not asked for actionBar(Of-course it's rectangle) but I have asked for 'actionBar_Icon'(the app icon or ic_launcher.PNG).I want it to be rectangular as you have highlighted in the image.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "action bar icon". I have masked information on the action bar red/orange boxes I have in this screenshot. The masked areas include text and a square icon (the application's icon) in the upper left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can inspect all the styles by looking at `styles.xml` in your android SDK platforms folder. e.g.,

`<your-sdk-dir>/platforms/android-16/data/res/values/styles.xml`

looking at API level 16, this is what i see,

```
<style name="Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    ...
```

if that resource is not public, your best bet is to set the action bar background and your footer background to something you define. you do this by creating a theme in your `styles.xml` and overriding the action bar style,

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

now create the actual action bar style,

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_background</item>
</style>
```

now assign this style to your application,

```
<application
    ...   
    android:theme="@style/Theme" >
...
```

Comment: I see the styles.xml where you've specified. It doesn't look I can set my a control's layout to this as the Resource is not public.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself looking for the colors values inside xml files. I couldn't find it. In the end the most stupid idea was the best:

Print screen of emulator and color picker in gimp. This matched exactly the color I've been looking for.

For me this answer is really stupid. However at the end of a day I've been able to find value very quickly.